# When moving an Android App to the SD Card, none of the downloaded assets move with it

Tags: android, android-sdcard

So I have made my app moveable to the SD card, but the assets that you get from the app (Levels, pics, videos) stay on the internal storage. It was my understanding that moving to the SD card took care of that. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you saving the assets to storage?

Comment: It is unclear what you consider to be the assets of the app.